# i cant create a table because name is invalid

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Im trying to create a table with the name " Order " and these datatypes (Note: i dont have a table named Order and I tried to create other tables and it worked ) and the names are:

```
create table Order(
Onum    Number(8) PRIMARY KEY,
Odate   Date,
Otime   Time(7),
Delivered_on_time   char(1));
```

and the error was:

invalid table name

so I tried to name it Ordeer and try again and it gave me this error:

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

4. ```
   Otime   Time(7),
   ```
5. ```
   Delivered_on_time   char(1)
   ```
6. );

what to do? help please

Comment: `ORDER` is a reserved word, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words. Can't be used as table name unless delimited as `"ORDER"`. But I'd consider `ORDERS` instead.

Comment: Oracle also lists [reserved words in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Oracle-SQL-Reserved-Words.html#GUID-55C49D1E-BE08-4C50-A9DD-8593EB925612). And it lists [data types](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-A3C0D836-BADB-44E5-A5D4-265BA5968483); `time` is not one of them. There isn't a time-only type (that you can use anyway), but you don't need one, as dates include time components.

Comment: Oracle does not have a `TIME` data type.

Comment: @AlexPoole You could use the `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data type to represent a time. But in this case, since `DATE` has a time component then the OP should have no need to try to do something like that.

Comment: Also `CHAR` is not recommended - use `VARCHAR2` instead.

Comment: Sure, but you'd you'd have to constrain it to act like time of day. Or you could use a string, or number of seconds, or whatever. None of them are really a 'time'. <shrug>

Answer (score 4):

First, you can't call the table `order` because `order` is a reserved word.  (There's a tricky way to get around this, but it's a bad idea to do so.)

Second, the `DATE` type also includes the time, so you don't need to have separate date and time columns.

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    onum              NUMBER(8) PRIMARY KEY,
    odate             DATE,
    delivered_on_time CHAR(1)
);
```

Comment: You can call the table `ORDER`; the OP would just need to use a quoted identifier `"ORDER"` and to always use quoted identifiers (and the same case) whenever they refer to the table. Saying that they "can't" is wrong as they can (but they should not as it is bad practice).